# Trying to get an ASP report to run a SQL against 2 tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vbscript

I know that this is an older way of doing things, but I have to stick with what I have at the time. Currently I am trying to get my ASP report to go against 2 different SQL tables and I can't seem to get it right.

Below is a section of what I am working on. Any help to get this to work would be great as all I am getting is an error 500. Yes I do run it on the server and yes I have turned off friendly error messages.

```
 <%@ Language = "VBScript" %>
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=windows-1252">
    <TITLE>AUTO AID EVENTS</TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

    </HEAD>
    <BODY> 

    <%
    'These next three lines 
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
    Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
    Response.Expires = 0

    'SQLOLEDB Connection...(used so that the Timeout config can be set)
    dim myConn
    Set myConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    myConn.CommandTimeout = 0  'Unlimited timeout period
    myConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=server; Initial Catalog=data1;  enter code here`enter code here`User ID=user; Password=password"

   set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


   SQL = " SELECT dgroup, cdts, sub_tycod, num_1, prim_unit, xterm FROM agency_event WHERE dgroup = 'FIRE' and sub_tycod = 'AUTOAID' and cdts > '20150501%' and "
SQL = SQL +" xterm <> '150003l' ORDER BY num_1 "

    'response.write (SQL)

    rs.open SQL, myConn

    If rs.EOF then 
       Response.write "--No EVENTS Found--"
       'Response.end
    end if

    'rs.MoveFirst

    %>

    <TABLE BORDER=4 BGCOLOR=#ffffff CELLSPACING=0><FONT FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000><CAPTION><B>EVENT BY AGENCY</B></CAPTION></FONT>

    <THEAD>
    <TR>
    <TH BGCOLOR=#c0c0c0 BORDERCOLOR=#000000 ><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt" FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000 
         >&nbsp; AGENCY &nbsp;</FONT></TH>
    <TH BGCOLOR=#c0c0c0 BORDERCOLOR=#000000 ><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt" FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000 
         >&nbsp; EVENT &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TH>
    <TH BGCOLOR=#c0c0c0 BORDERCOLOR=#000000 ><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt" FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000 
         >&nbsp; FIRE CASE NUMBER &nbsp;</FONT></TH>     
    <TH BGCOLOR=#c0c0c0 BORDERCOLOR=#000000 ><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt" FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000 
         >&nbsp; PRIMARY UNIT &nbsp;</FONT></TH>
    <TH BGCOLOR=#c0c0c0 BORDERCOLOR=#000000 ><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt" FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000 
         >Sub Event Description </FONT></TH>     
    </TR>
    </THEAD>
    <TBODY>

    <%

    Do Until rs.EOF
    %>

    <TR VALIGN=top>

    <!--FIRST COLUMN -->
    <%If Not IsNull(rs.Fields("dgroup")) then%>
    <TD BORDERCOLOR=#c0c0c0 >
          <FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt" FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>
          <%=Server.HTMLEncode(rs.Fields("dgroup").Value)%></FONT>
    <%else%>
    <TD BORDERCOLOR=#c0c0c0 >
          <FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt" FACE="Arial" COLOR=#C0C0C0>
          <%=Server.HTMLEncode("<null>")%></FONT>
    <%end if%>      
    </TD>
```

Comment: Why do you have a percent sign in this part of your SQL string?:   ... and cdts > '20150501%' and ...   It's not valid SQL Server syntax.

Comment: the table is a calendar date table and the info in the field looks like this 20150506150322ED. I am looking for information that starts on this date and nothing prior to it as we have a lot of test records in the field.

Comment: But in IIS7 if you want to actually see the message you must run this from the server. Then the messages will display in the browser. I would HIGHLY recommend you stop using deprecated html tags like font. You also should be putting your values inside quotes (single or double doesn't matter as long as they are consistent). Then you really need to look at using css instead of inline style on everything. This just makes it harder on you than it needs to be.

Comment: I guess I should have put that I am running II6 with this and not 7 or 8. as for running it from the server i have and i get the wonderful message of "An error has occurred" and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid SQL syntax:

```
cdts > '20150501%'
```

a more correct way to do this:

> the info in the field looks like this 20150506150322ED. I am looking
>   for information that starts on this date and nothing prior to it

would be something like this:

```
CAST(LEFT(cdts, 8) AS date) > '20150501'
```

Comment: While I do appreciate the fix for the cdts table, which by the way I did implement. I am still looking to see how I would join 2 tables and get the info that I need.

Comment: that part of your question isn't clear.   There is only one table referenced in your code.